# Add additional property to Observable array based on another array

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I have two Observable arrays type of `Observable<MyType>`

```
export interface MyType{
  title: string;
  id: string;
  other: [];
}
```

I want to add additional property `exists` to the first array and set it to `true` if the item is exists in the second array:

```
  const combined$ = combineLatest(this.first$, this.second$);
    this.output$ = combined.pipe(
      map((x, y) => {
        return x.map(a => {
          a.title = a.title;
          a.id = a.id;
          a.other = a.other;
          a.exists = y.find(b => b.id === a.id )
        });
      })
    );
```

Always getting `[...undefined]` result if subscribing to the `output` observable `this.output$.subscribe(console.log);`

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please be aware that [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns the element found in the array (otherwise *undefined*). Better use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). Plus, when you return the object on the map, you should use either a regular `return` statement or an object enclosed in parenthesis.

```
const combined$ = combineLatest(this.first$, this.second$);
this.output$ = combined.pipe(
    map(([x, y]) => {
        return x.map(a => {
            return { 
                ...a,
                exists: y.some(b => b.id === a.id)
            };
         });
     })
);
```

Comment: interesting getting `exists` always `undefined` was trying to `debug` by: `y.some(b => {  debugger; return b.id=== a.id;})` but `debug` not getting hit, same thing in case of `.find` never hit debugger so `exists` always `undefined`

Comment: debug the `map` inside the pipe, to check what are you getting returned from `x` and `y`. They should be arrays, otherwise additional checks must be placed.

Comment: Yeah seems like all good now. However why you do `map(([x, y])` but not `map((x, y)`  What is the difference?

Comment: `combineLatest` returns an array of the most recent values from each input Observable. See the docs: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest

Answer (score 2):

I think combined sends one value which is an array of individual values. here `y` would be undefined.

Use ([x,y]) to destructure the values inside map and try again.
The combined$ also has a typo that you missed.
And `find` can be replaced with `some` to better represent the logic and return a Boolean

Also when you are using `x.map` you are mapping the wrong array logically.

```
const combined$ = combineLatest(this.first$, this.second$);
this.output$ = combined$.pipe(
  map(([x, y]) => {
    return x.map(a => {
      a.title = a.title;
      a.id = a.id;
      a.other = a.other;
      a.exists = y.some(b => b.id === a.id )
    });
  })
);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code snippet you have a typo where you set the result from the combinedLatest rxjs operator as `combined$`, then you call it as `combined` the next line, which I assume is incorrect, or just a translation error when transitioning this issue to SO. (regardless, have to point it out hehe)

Next, the `combineLatest` operator returns an array of all the observables. As such, you can easily get the latest values from all the observables using destructuring, within the `map` operator.

Below is the final code:

```js
const combined$ = combineLatest(this.first$, this.second$);
this.output$ = combined.pipe(
  map(([x, y]) => {
    return x.map(a => {
      a.title = a.title;
      a.id = a.id;
      a.other = a.other;
      a.exists = y.find(b => b.id === a.id )
    });
  })
);
```

In the original code, you were essentially passing an array of the values as `x`.